# If $\int_a^b u(t)v(t)$ exists for every $v \in C_0^\infty(a,b)$, does $\int_a^b u(t)$ exist?

Tags: measure-theory

If $\int_a^b u(t)v(t)$ exists for every $v \in C_0^\infty(a,b)$, does $\int_a^b u(t)$ exist? Is $u$ measurable?

I think yes since we can approximate the function $1$ by infinitely differentiable functions. Am I right?

Comment: The problem is trivial as stated since $(a,b)$ is a finite interval... The constant functions are $C^\infty(a,b)$ and vanishing at infinity is not relevant... Anyhow, for any finite interval, you can find a $C^\infty$ function which is one on that interval...

Comment: @N.S. what do you mean vanishing at infinity? $C_0^\infty$ means non-zero only on a compact set contained in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I presume you meant … compact set contained in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @aere Different people use different meaning for $C_0$, in my research i always saw it used for functions vanishing at infinity ;)

Comment: @N.S. oh sorry. Never seen that before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u$ would have to be measurable on every subinterval $(a+\delta,b-\delta)$, and therefore on $(a,b)$. But $u$ could have arbitrarily bad behaviour near the end points. For example, $$u(x)=\frac{1}{(x-a)(b-x)}$$ would satisfy the conditions, yet not be integrable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: But $u$ is definitely measurable. Thanks.